# mktime equivalent in php 5.3

Tags: php, mktime

Hi I just updated to php 5.3.

I use `mktime()` in a script:

```
$DateSec = mktime($Hour, $Minutes, $Seconds, $Month, $Day, $Year, 0);
```

What would be the equivalent function in PHP 5.3?

Comment: You *have* to use the `$dst` parameter? Are you using the overflow functionality of `mktime`, or are you always passing values which are in range?

Comment: It would be nice if you put as well into your question *why* that usage is a problem after you upgraded to PHP-5.3. This information might be of much use for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mktime.php

You use it well, just remove the last argument.

```
mktime($Hour, $Minutes, $Seconds, $Month, $Day, $Year);
```

Is not deprecated.

If you want to use specific timezones, look at this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: "As of PHP 5.1, when called with no arguments, mktime() throws an E_STRICT notice" cf. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `mktime()` does still work in PHP 5.3, and it does still have a place. But personally, I much prefer to use the new DateTime classes for all my date handling. They are significantly better all round than the old functions.

Take a look at [the DateTime class manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). It has some stuff that might interest you.

For example, this is how you would replace `mktime()` using the new OO methods:

```
$date = new DateTime();    
$date->setDate($year, $month, $day);
$date->setTime($hour, $mins, $secs);
```

But this might also be of interest:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2009-02-15 15:16:17')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
strtotime('2015-04-30 17:00:00');
```

which could be combined with date function to mimic `mktime` defaults like this :

```
strtotime(date('Y').'-04-30');
```